# ModuleNotFoundError, even after pip install

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I have recently bought a new laptop and was viewing some python projects of mine which I made on my pc. For one of them I use the `python-bitvavo-api` library which I installed using `pip3 install python-bitvavo-api`. The version I installed is 1.2.2 which is the latest on their website.

Now when I try to import it using this code: `from python_bitvavo_api.bitvavo import Bitvavo`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\indig\OneDrive\Documenten\Python Projects\Personal\Cryptone\Cryptone.py", line 6, in <module>
    from python_bitvavo_api.bitvavo import Bitvavo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_bitvavo_api'
```

I read online that it may occur when using multiple python versions, Im only using 1 and thats python 3.7

Btw. I have the same error with the Pillow module, so it might be a setting in visual studio that I dont know of. Anyway, someone please help. If you need more details please ask.

Comment: How are you running this?  Command line?  Inside Visual Studio?  Inside VSCode?  It's quite possible that your IDE has included its own installation of Python.

Comment: I agree with @TimRoberts.  Check where you installed it and the version that you are running...  `import sys`  ,  `sys.version_info`.

Comment: sys.version_info gives: `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`

How do I view where I installed it?

Comment: I found it, I installed it in: `c:\users\indig\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages`
My python instance is located in: `C:\Users\indig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

How are you running it? From the terminal or from VS?
You can also check the installed libraries running the command pip list

Comment: I am running it from VS. I have already done that, and it says that it is correctly installed and has version 1.2.2

Comment: This is not an answer.  It should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: Ok so maybe the interpreter selected in VS is not the correct one. Try to press Ctrl+Alt+P and search for Select Interpreter. Otherwise, I strongly advise you to create a virtual env for your project in order to isolate it from others and install again all the required packaged.

Comment: When I press Ctrl+Alt+P it brings up the `Attach to process` window, it doesnt find a Select Interpreter.

Comment: I have a virtual environment with Python3.7 running in VS, but I have no clue how that all works.

Comment: Ok, that is probably why. You have installed the package locally and not in your venv. Open the terminal, go into your project directory, activate the venv (/path/to/venv/bin/activate) and then you can start installing the packages.

Comment: I found the solution, on the  right side of visual studio you have the option to install packages in your environment. I totally looked over this, but using this to install the module worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great, there are many ways of doing it. Personally, I prefer to work on the terminal and be sure that VS code is using the correct interpreter. When creating a venv in your project dir, the interpreter selected in VS should be stored in your project dir. Check around how to work with a venv, it's quite important to avoi such issue

Comment: @TimRoberts I know but I couldn't add any comment because of my reputation rank. Just wanted to help somehow.